# Why do my Python PIL imports not working?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, python-import, python-imaging-library

When I am working with the PIL, I have to import a tons of PIL modules. I was experimenting with three ways to do this, but only the last one works despite all is being logical to me:

Importing the complete PIL and calling it's modules in the code: NOPE

```
>>> import PIL
>>> image = PIL.Image.new('1', (100,100), 0) 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Image'
```

Importing everything from PIL: NOPE

```
>>> from PIL import *
>>> image = Image.new('1', (100,100), 0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Image' is not defined
```

importing some modules from PIL: OK

```
>>> from PIL import Image
>>> image = Image.new('1', (100,100), 0)
>>> image
<PIL.Image.Image image mode=1 size=100x100 at 0xB6C10F30>
>>> # works...
```

What did I not get here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PIL doesn't import any submodules on it's own. This is actually pretty common.

So when you use `from PIL import Image`, you actually locate the `Image.py` file and import that, whereas when you attempt to just call `PIL.Image` after `import PIL`, you're attempting an attribute lookup on an empty module (*since you didn't import any submodules*).

The same reasoning applies for why `from PIL import *` won't work - you need to explicitly import the Image submodule. In any case, `from ... import *` is seen as bad practice due to the namespace pollution that will occur - your best bet is to use `from PIL import Image`.

Further, PIL is no longer being maintained, but for backwards compatibility purposes should you use `from PIL import Image` you can ensure your code will remain compatible with the still-maintained [Pillow](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (as oppposed to just using `import Image`).